# Vandermonde matrix with polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let us consider the simple Vandermonde matrix $V_n$ with $V_{ij} = \omega^{(i - 1)(j - 1)}$ where $\omega = e^{2i\pi/n}$. Its well known that for a column vector $A$, $VA$ is equivalent to evaluating the polynomial $f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} a_{i+1} x^i$, at each power of $\omega$. i.e. $(V_nA)_i = f(\omega^i)$. It is interesting to note that $V_n^{2n} = n^nI$.

Let us consider a polynomial $f$, and generate $V_n(f)$, where $V_n(f)_{ij} = \omega^{f(i, j)}$. Notice that the default matrix is generated by $f(i, j) = (i - 1)(j - 1)$. Notice $V_n(f)$ is not necessarily Vandermonde. I found for $f(i, j) = (i - 1)(j - 1) - (i - 1)^2$, we get $V_7(f)^{14} = 7^7 \times I$. I don't have any proof for its correctness.

Is the following conjecture true -

For any polynomial function $f(i, j)$ with coefficients coprime to $n$, with $\det(V_n(f)) \not= 0$, $V_n(f)^{2n} = n^n \times I$.

Here is some playground code to test it on. It uses the field $Z_p$ and it's primitive roots for convenience.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
constexpr int modpow(int base, int pow, int mod){
    int ans = 1;
    while(pow > 0){
        if(pow % 2 > 0){
            ans = (1ll * ans * base) % mod;
        }
        base = (1ll * base * base) % mod;
        pow >>= 1;
    }
    return ans;
}
template<int n, int m, int mod>
struct Matrix{
    array<array<int, m>, n> M;
    Matrix(){}
    template<int k>
    Matrix<n, k, mod> operator*(Matrix<m, k, mod> O){
        Matrix<n, k, mod> ans = Matrix<n, k, mod>::zero();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                for(int l=0;l<k;l++){
                    ans[i][l] += (1ll * M[i][j] * O[j][l]) % mod;
                    if(ans[i][l] >= mod) ans[i][l] -= mod;
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
    Matrix<n, m, mod> operator*(int x){
        Matrix<n, m, mod> ans;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                ans[i][j] = (1ll * M[i][j] * x) % mod;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
    auto& operator[](int x){
        return M[x];
    }
    bool operator==(Matrix O){
        bool ans = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) for(int j=0;j<m;j++) ans &= (M[i][j] == O[i][j]);
        return ans;
    }
    static Matrix zero(){
        Matrix M;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) for(int j=0;j<m;j++) M[i][j] = 0;
        return M;
    }
    static Matrix identity(){
        Matrix M;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) for(int j=0;j<m;j++) M[i][j] = (i == j);
        return M;
    }
};
int main(){
    constexpr int mod = 17;
    constexpr int g = 3; // g must be a primitive root of mod
    constexpr int N = 4; // n must be a divisor of (mod - 1)
    static_assert((mod - 1) % N == 0);
    constexpr int omega = modpow(g, (mod - 1) / N, mod);
    constexpr int order = 2 * N;
    auto f = [&](int i, int j){
        return i * j - i * i;
    };
    Matrix<N, N, mod> V;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        V[i][j] = modpow(omega, f(i, j) % N + N, mod);
    }
    Matrix<N, N, mod> Vpow = Matrix<N, N, mod>::identity();
    for(int i=0;i<order;i++){
        Vpow = (Vpow * V);
    }
    /*for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            cout<<Vpow[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }*/
    assert((Vpow == Matrix<N, N, mod>::identity() * modpow(N, order / 2, mod)));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tips for clarity: The $f$ in your first paragraph and the $f$ in the latter paragraphs are unrelated: this is highly confusing, please don't do this. (And if you absolutely must give the identity matrix a name instead of just calling it $1$, then do say what “$I$” is.)

Comment: Concerning the conjecture itself: any function on $\{1,\ldots,n\}^2$ can be written as a polynomial (and I don't think your restriction of having coefficients coprime to $n$ brings much: if $n$ is prime then clearly it doesn't), so unless you're going to put a bound on the degree of the polynomial, or something like that, you're just asking a question about *any* $n\times n$ matrix with $n$-th roots of unity as coefficients. So you might as well rewrite it like that.

Comment: I know this is a bit off-topic, but you should not use the header `<bits/stdc++.h>` since it is not a standard header file. Other compilers may not implement it and hence your code is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your conjecture is true, even for Vandermonde matrices... For $n=3$, it is known that

$$
V_3^2 = 3\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0 \end{pmatrix},
$$

So it should as well be that

$$
V_3^6 = 3^3\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0 \end{pmatrix},
$$

which is not $n^n I$? Note that on the other hand it is true that $V_n^4 = n^2 I$ and $V_n^{4k} = n^{2k} I$ for any $n$, from which you possibly deducted your initial conjecture about Vandermonde matrices.